# Spline Interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation, spline

I have four questions about splines. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

1) Boundary conditions for cubic spline interpolation to a set of data
$a=x{}_{1}<x2<...<x_{m} , $
like for example $not-a-knot$ or $Natural$ give respectively the knot sequences:
$t_{NK}=(x_{1},x_{1},x_{1},x_{1},x_{3},x_{4},...x_{m-2},x_{m},x_{m},x_{m},x_{m})$ and 
$t_{N}=(x_{1},x_{1},x_{1},x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},...x_{m-1},x_{m},x_{m},x_{m},x_{m})$.

But if I want to interpolate with periodic end conditions:
$D^{j}g(a)=D^{j}g(b),$ for $j=1,2$ ,                                                                                            then what is the corresponding knot sequence (and why) ?

2) Suppose I want to interpolate a function defined on a grid of size $h$.
What does it mean, mathematically, that cardinal B-splines have $h-independent$ $ L^{\infty} $$norm$ (and why)?

3) What is exactly a "cardinal" spline ? Are splines with the above knot sequences considered as cardinal splines ?

4) Would there be somewhere I could find an algorithm that can construct a parametric tensor product cubic cardinal B-spline interpolant (if I am not saying something wrong), that is fast for evaluation of the constructed interpolant (and ideally the matlab code) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) $(x_1, \ldots, x_m)$, to get the right dimension for the spline space (to match the number of constraints).

(2) It means that the cardinal b-splines have $L_\infty$ norm (maximum absolute value) that is independent of the grid size, $h$. I'm not sure why this would be the case. Need more context to explain further.

(3) A cardinal spline is one that has the value 1 at one interpolation point, and zero at all others. So, it's a statement about the *values* of the spline function, not about its knots. So, it doesn't make sense to ask whether or not the splines you mentioned are cardinal splines, since you didn't say anything about values.

(4) Some time ago there was a "spline toolkit" in Matlab. The code was written by Carl deBoor, based on his book "A Practical Guide to Splines" (which I highly recommend). Looking at the Matlab web site, the spline toolkit seems to have disappeared, and they are now talking about a "Curve Fitting" package, instead. But, anyway, it looks like a lot of the original code/functions are still present. For tensor product interpolation, look at [this document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/multivariate-tensor-product-splines.html), or look at deBoor's book.

Comment: Thanks for the book reference. But in the book, it is stated that "...One is the uniform knot sequence, $\mathbb{Z}=(...,-1,0,1,2,...)$. The corresponding B-splines are called cardinal. So as I understand it cardinal splines are defined by this uniform knot sequence. As B-splines depend on a finite knot sequence, my question still remains; are B-splines with knot sequences like above considered as cardinal B-splines ?

Comment: Still from the book you mention, I have found this interpolation norm, $\parallel I_{4}\parallel:=max\{\parallel I_{4}\parallel/\parallel f\parallel,f\in C^{0},f\neq0\}$ but I did not find if and where it is proved that this norm is h-independent. For the spline toolbox in Matlab, it works but I am looking for something that is faster (if possible maybe it is already highly optimized).

Comment: If you want something faster than Matlab, try the original code from deBoor's book. It's in Fortran, as I recall, but transcription into other languages should not be too hard.

Comment: It looks like different people use the word "cardinal" in different ways. In my world, equally-spaced knots are called "uniform" knots, and the corresponding splines are called "uniform" splines. Of course, a uniform knot sequence can always be shifted/scaled so that the knots become integers. Non-uniform knot sequences are much more common. If your splines are also rational (rather than polynomial), then you have NURBS curves (Non-Uniform Rational B-Spline curves).